# Multiple Wordpress Blogs in 12.04

Tags: server, apache2, wordpress

I've got an ubuntu server hosted up at Amazon. I'm using virtual hosts, and I already have that somewhat set up. (i.e. wiki.mydomain.com is my mediawiki which is running). I'm installing Mediawiki per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WordPress and I can easily get ONE blog going. However, I'm confused by the line

```
Also if you plan on hosting multiple blogs with different virtual hosts, each needs a differently named database, which would be achieved in the same way.
```

I want to have two blogs, ideally at blog1.mydomain.com and blog2.mydomain.com, but I would settle for blogs.mydomain.com/blog1 and blogs.mydomain.com/blog2 I just can't tell how to do this. Do I just run the install script multiple times? Won't I need two folders in /var/www that have separate symlinks? If anyone has done this, I would appreciate a little help. I've done a ton of development, but this is my first LAMP server so I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look like you are trying to use Multi Site for Wordpress. the note above would mean if you have multiple blogs across different sub domains or domains. in the case of having a blogs.yoursite.com/blog1, blog2, etc, you may want to look at [Create a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) on the Wordpress site. That will mean you only have one install, and one DB setup, and Wordpress sorts out the rest. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'm working on this now, and it is exactly what I am looking for.